# How do you set a delegate for a protocol in a viewcontroller in another tab?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, delegates, protocols

I would like some expert MVC design feedback please:

I have a UITabBarController with 2 tabs, each of the tabs leads to a Nav controller with a stack of VC.

The last view Controller on the 1st tab path will show an image. I would like that image to be stored in a table and viewed anytime the second tab is selected.

How do I send this image from the 1st tab-> NaVController->last VC (image VC) to 2nd tab -> NavController->table VC?

I have a couple of options:

1- Create a class method in the tableVC and have the imageVC call that class method and pass that image to be saved directly into user defaults. This seems to go against MVC

2- Create a protocol in imageVC with a method and delegate property and have the table VC adopt that method to save the image in an array. The problem here is that the only place to set the delegate is in ViewDidLoad:

```
[[[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] setDelegate:self];
```

The problem here is that if the user select the second tab from the start, the app will crash because obviously the viewControllers have not been loaded on the nav stack for the first tab. In the same token, if the user sees 1 image first and then selects the second tab, it will execute and set the delegate but without saving that first selected image.

There must be an easier way.....

Thanks in advance
KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should separate your data model from your view controllers a little more. Following the MVC approach, a model should not know about how its represented. So, making a change to the model in `ImageVC` should not involve direct calls to any other VC.

I'd create a separate entity, e.g. `SelectedImages`, and add images from `ImageVC` to it, and have `TableVC` read from it when it needs to display itself. `SelectedImages` could be a property in the app delegate, a Core Data entity, a singleton class, or something like that.

Comment: I thought in the MVC model, the model should only be used by its VC. By having the SelectedImages read by the TableVC, wouldn't that be making that model available to both MVCs? Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's OK for multiple VCs to use the same model. Like in your case, you have one VC for adding data to the model, and another for viewing the model as a table. That's totally normal. Another example: a spreadsheet with some numbers, and a chart plotted from those numbers, are using the same model, but they're 2 completely different VCs.

Comment: just to be clear here. Are you saying that the common model class would be a class with class methods that would be called to set and retrieve images. From what I know of MVC, instance methods would not work here.

Comment: I would personally use a singleton for the model like yours. Or you could just have an object that you pass around, e.g. through the app delegate, but the singleton is a much cleaner solution.

Comment: If I am using a singleton, would there be a way to save/retrieve the images to a "class variable" NSMutableArray or are we stuck using the user preferences (NSUSerDefaults objectForKey and setObjectForKey...)

Comment: I just don't see why do you need static variables if you have a singleton (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Maybe I don't understand your question. Can you explain a little more why is a singleton not enough for what you do?

Comment: Now I see how singleton works.But what bugged me w/using the same model (class) for 2 different contr. in the MVC was the following: Where 2 contr. need to share indirectly a model, can they do that without needing to set and retrieve from NSUSerdefaults (maybe that image list is not part of the user preference and is zeroed at start of each app launch). So I tested with static vars and declared in that model class, outside of "class methods", a static NSMutableArray to store the image list and for class1 to set it and class2 to retrieve it using class methods.It worked. Any negatives here?

Comment: Your solution works, at least for simple cases. If you're comfortable with it, and your project is fairly small, the you're good. This kind of solution, though, wouldn't pass a code review at the places I've worked. So in my answer I suggested solution that seems a bit more complicated at first, but is more scalable, and more conforming to the principles of good design (since in your question you've asked for feedback on MVC design). But in the end, you choose a solution that works best for YOU and your project.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the AppDelegate be the delegate for both of the VCs.  Then when first tab selects an image it can do some sort of `[self.delegate setTheImage:theImage];` call.  And the second tab can have a call to its delegate (the AppDelegate) that goes something like `theImage = [self.delegate getTheImage];`.  If an image is not yet selected then have the AppDelegate pass nil and check for `theImage == nil` before displaying the second tab (and maybe put up some sort of interface object that let's the user know what is going on).

Here is some code for setting up the AppDelegate as the Delegate:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.delegate = appDelegate;
```

Then your AppDelegate can have a property for the image like 'theImage':

```
-(void) setTheImage:(UIImage *)image:
{
    self.theImage = image;
}

-(UIImage *) getTheImage
{
    if(self.theImage)
        return self.theImage;
    else
        return nil;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

option 2 variant :

The MainVC could adopt the ImageVC protocol and set the image to TableVC.
TableVC have to be MainVC attribute